# Website sizes on different screens

Tags: html, css, image, web, alignment

So, I'll attempt to keep this brief. I am trying to design my site (it is 100% raw) and when I give it to other friends to view, the images and text are not inline and I'm not too sure how I should combat this, I have posted my code so if there is anyone that could lend a hand I'd appreciate it. Thanks.

---> Code - http://pastebin.com/8J2tqd8J

Comment: Please add the HTML you have.

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about is called *responsive website design.*

There are a number of solutions, from using CSS `@media` queries, to using responsive sizing units like `vw` or `rem`.

However, to make our lives simpler, there is a framework that does all the heavy lifting for us -- Twitter's Bootstrap. Just include the required libraries in your head tags, and start using their class names.

[Here is a great introduction](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/) to how it works.

The essentials that you would include in the `<head>` *(or you can stick the js links at the bottom, just before the `</body>` tags - your call)* are:

```
<head>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
```

Of course, you would still have the other things in the `<head>`, such as DocType, Title, your own stylesheet, your own js file (if required), etc. The above just demonstrates how you can reference all required libraries from online CDNs without needing to download/install anything onto your webserver.

Comment: I've added those head tags however I was wondering if the CSS link was needed? As I have already styled my entire site and the bootstrap one sort of discards/merges with mine.

I tried removing the CSS tag from bootstrap however it made the site a little off measurements.

http://baseframe.co/a/ - If you look here, on mobile (or if you make your window smaller) the div text goes a little crazy.

Comment: If the bootstrap stylesheet is referenced *before* your stylesheet, then any same-named styles will be overwritten by your stylesheet. This is a common situation and many of us over-ride the bootstrap styling here and there, as needed. And yes, the Bootstrap stylesheet is definitely required.